Relationship of disease to alternative strand - microRNA-3p or -5p
I am working in a project involving microRNAs in a cohort of patients (controls and cases of coronary artery disease). I got results from sequencing of HDL-lipoprotein involving diferentially expressed genes which could be down or upregulated in cases/controls.
I don't have much experience working with miRNA but I got results involving e.g. hsa-miR-28-3p as a significant molecule and implicated according to miRDB, TargetScan or miRTarBase in several pathways that are related to the disease I am working. The thing is in the search I found that hsa-miR-28-5p is related to my disease as well, as is hsa-let-7e5p and hsa-let-7a5p. I don't have much experience in this topic, DEG microRNAs in -3p, to which extent is related this finding with findings in same microRNA -5p. As far as I know the nomenclature reference in which strand was found to interact the microRNA under observation
Apart from the sources I mentioned before (miRDB, TargetScan or miRTarBase) where is possible to find disease-associted evidence with microRNAs? Or pathways?

Can you include some links or other information? What exactly do you see with differential expression? "Associated with disease" is a pretty generic statement. Why would you expect associations mechanistically?

This is really a request for literature references, but you can find these from an internet search for the microRNAs of interest, perhaps coupled with “disease”.

@MaximilianPress — Association is all one can say. Cause and effect follow, if indeed there is such. As for expectation, this is irrelevant if there is an observation.

I see a differentially expressed genes in a sequencing standard procedures. The results concluded in a set of genes up,or downregulated in cases versus control. What I mean is, the relationship of finding certain x-5p, how is this related with x-3p? If x-5p is widely described in an specific tumor (breast), has it been studied the impact of finding x-3p?

As far as I know, not all the databases are based on experimental evidence, just mirTarBase. If "mechanisitically" involves experimental evidence, it's better than in silico. However my question is pretty generic, afterwards my feeling is I cannot extrapolate the behaviour of x-5p/x-3p for y-5p/y-3p

Is your main concern whether it is valid to expect an effect on a 5’p microRNA to hold true for the 3’p complement? The answer to that is obviously not.

For pathway associations, the generic answer is Gene Ontology, which does appear to annotate microRNAs (see section "Annotating MicroRNA clusters").
One could imagine annotating microRNAs with respect to their targets' functional annotations mechanistically.
However I'd like answers to my questions in comments.
